# C++ std::map, rotation of keys

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, rotation

I need to implement something like "first key rotation" in map. A more detailed explanation of the problem. There is a map:

```
std::map <double, double> test;
```

The following elements are inserted:

```
test[0.5] = 15;
test[1] = 20;
test[2.3] = 12;
test[3.7] = 18
```

The rotation algorithm could be rewritten as:

a] Remember first element in map (element with the lowest key): rem_el = map[0] //Symbolic notation

b] Remove first element from map

c] Set new keys for all remaining elements in map:

```
map[i].key = map[i].key - rem_el.key
```

d] Add remembered key to the map with the new key: the sum of the last key and remembered key

```
test[rem_el.key + test[n-1].key] = rem_el.value
```

First rotation:

```
test[0.5] = 20;
test[1.8] = 12;
test[3.2] = 18;
test[3.7] = 15;
```

Second rotation:

```
test[1.3] = 12;
test[2.7] = 18;
test[3.2] = 15;
test[3.7] = 20;
```

There are n-1 rotation for such a map...

How to implement this operation as much as efficient (map with thousands of items)? I used list of all keys and another temporary map created from the rotated list, but this procedure is probably not optimal.

I could ask for some code samples? Thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing as “first element” in the map. Can you define “first” — is that the one with the lowest key value?

Comment: @Eugene: yes, this is the element with lowest key...

Comment: You should note that a map is not ordered. Hence this 'roation' idea des not make sense.

Comment: @Ed: But I am able to access map items using iterator. So I need to change the "order" of keys and values.

Comment: Apart of the things mentioned, do you need to read items by key?

Comment: @cellcortex: In further processing yes...

Comment: @Ed Heal: a map is ordered, it's sorted by key. You're thinking of `unordered_map` or `hash_map`.

Comment: @EugeneHomyakov: I would argue that `std::map::begin()` would yield the first element in a non-empty map.

Comment: A side note: keys in maps are compared for identity, and comparing `doubles` for identity is unwise, since two doubles can be really really close in value without being equal. I would consider a design change where you use some integer type as key. Software that works with currencies often use `int` to represents cents (rather than `doubles` representing dollars), perhaps something similar could work for you?

Comment: @RasmusStorjohann: Not true. Keys in maps are never compared for identity (`==`), they are only compared with the map's ordering relation (usually `<`). I agree that a `double` is still not (usually) a good key for a map.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need a deque of pairs, not a map:

```
std::deque<std::pair<double, double> > test;
```

You have to keep it sorted yourself if it's needed. Then it is all straightforward:

```
std::pair<double, double> rem_el = test.front();
test.pop_front();
for (std::deque<std::pair<double, double> >::
     iterator it = test.begin(); it != test.end(); ++it)
{
    it->first -= rem_el.first;
}
assert(!test.empty());
test.push_back(std::make_pair(rem_el.first + test.back().first, rem_el.second));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an amusing problem, but more about algorithms than data structures.

I'd note that `Map^i[n]` can be solved in constant time... if instead of modifying the structure you *tweak* the access.

From my understanding of the problem, the values simply "cycle": `[15, 20, 12, 18]` -> `[20, 12, 18, 15]` -> `[12, 18, 15, 20]` -> `[18, 15, 20, 12]`

Formula:

- let N be the size of the sequence - 1 and n in `[0, N]` an index in the sequence
- let i in `[0, N]` be an iteration
- `Value^i[n] = Value[n+i%(N+1)]`

The keys are different though:

- `[0.5, 1, 2.3, 3.7]` -> `[0.5, 1.8, 3.2, 3.7]` -> `[1.3, 2.7, 3.2, 3.7]` -> `[1.4, 1.9, 2.4, 3.7]`
- Let's try to see a pattern: `[a, b, c, d]` -> `[b-a, c-a, d-a, d]` -> `[c-b, d-b, d-b+a, d]` -> `[d-c, d-c+a, d-c+b, d]`

Make the pattern more pronounced:

```
0: [a    , b      , c      , d      , e      , f]
1: [b-a  , c-a    , d-a    , e-a    , f-a    , f]
2: [c-b  , d-b    , e-b    , f-b    , f-(a-b), f]
3: [d-c  , e-c    , f-c    , f-(a-c), f-(b-c), f]
4: [e-d  , f-d    , f-(a-d), f-(b-d), f-(b-e), f]
5: [f-e  , f-(a-e), f-(b-e), f-(c-e), f-(d-e), f]
```

Note that this is also cycles, somewhat, since applying the transformation once more would yield the original sequence.

Formula (we reuse the previous variables):

```
Key^i[n] = | n = N    => Key[N]
           | i = 0    => Key[n]
           | n <= N-i => Key[n+i] - Key[i-1]
           | n >  N-i => Key[N] - (Key[n+i % (N+1)] - Key[i-1])
```

The latter 3 lines can be aggregated in `(Key[n+i % (N+1)] - Key[i-1]) % Key[N]`, if we define (arbitrarily) `Key[-1] = 0`.

Now that we have our formulas, we need a structure with Random Access, I'll simply pick a `vector`.

Compilable example provided below (or see [ideone](http://ideone.com/5mxvC)), gives:

```
[ 0.5: 15, 1: 20, 2.3: 12, 3.7: 18 ]
[ 0.5: 20, 1.8: 12, 3.2: 18, 3.7: 15 ]
[ 1.3: 12, 2.7: 18, 3.2: 15, 3.7: 20 ]
[ 1.4: 18, 1.9: 15, 2.4: 20, 3.7: 12 ]
```

Example:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::pair<double, double> Pair;
typedef std::vector<Pair> Vector;

double key(Vector const& vec, size_t const i, size_t const n) {
  assert(n < vec.size() && "Wrong index");
  if (i == 0) { return vec[n].first; }

  size_t const N = vec.size() - 1;

  if (n == N) { return vec.back().first; }

  double const partial = vec[(n+i) % (N+1)].first - vec[(i-1) % (N+1)].first;
  return (n <= N-i) ? partial : partial + vec[N].first;
} // key

double value(Vector const& vec, size_t const i, size_t const n) {
  assert(n < vec.size() && "Wrong index");
  return vec[(n+i) % vec.size()].second;      
} // value

int main() {
  Vector vec{ Pair(0.5, 15), Pair(1, 20), Pair(2.3, 12), Pair(3.7, 18) };
  sort(vec.begin(), vec.end()); // just to be sure

  size_t const size = vec.size();
  for (size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
    std::cout << "[ ";
    for (size_t n = 0; n != size; ++n) {
      if (n != 0) { std::cout << ", "; }
      std::cout << key(vec, i, n) << ": " << value(vec, i, n);
    }
    std::cout << " ]\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: @abcdef: I noticed a while ago that even though brute forcing works most of the time, when you want efficiency, you need to take a step back. Trying to optmize the implementation of particular algorithm is one thing, but the greatest leaps forward often stem from changing the algorithm altogether :)

Answer (score 1):

**Rotating values and keeping keys**

One possibility is to use `deque` as mentioned by @Eugene. Then, of course, you do not have the fast O(log n) access to the keys. If you want to keep the map then the following would be possible to "rotate" the map `m` by `n` rounds:

```
void rotate(map<double, double>& m, int n) {
    vector<double> values(m.size());
    int j = 0;
    for (map<double, double>::const_iterator i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); ++i, ++j) {
        values[j] = (*i).second;
    }
    j = n;
    for (map<double, double>::iterator i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); ++i, ++j) {
        m[(*i).first] = values[j % m.size()];
    }   
}
```

If you want to rotate several times by various number of rounds then you could make the vector `values` global and fill it only once. Also, it should be considered that rotating by `n1` and then by `n2` equals the rotation by `n1 + n2`. So, e.g. to get all rotations you would call:

```
rotate(m, 1);
rotate(m, 1); // 1 again
...
```

Just a remark: it is rather problematic to use doubles as keys.

**Rotating values and changing keys** (edited)

In this case a completely new map needs to be constructed as @abcdef already does. However, it seems that the new keys are not defined properly in the question. The keys k1, k2, ..., kn are transformed to k2-k1, k3-k1, ..., kn-k1, kn. We get duplicate keys if e.g. k[n-1] - k1 = kn, as when transforming (-1, 2, 5, 6) to (3, 6, 7, 6).

Comment: Take a closer look at key value set. Keys are not simply rotated. Their values are modified too.

Comment: If the deque is sorted, you can have O(log(n)) access to keys.

Comment: @UncleBens: a sorted deque could not be rotated, or a re-sort would be needed after each rotation. But the whole stuff with the transformed keys is strange anyhow.

Comment: @ tyz: I extended my answer based on your comment. The key transformation seems strange.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that std::map is based on tree structure and its elements have an ascending order. Described rotation operation does not change relative key positions. So key changes should not brake the map structure. I've created rotate function that modifies key values. It seems to be bad practice, still [it](http://www.ideone.com/f22wI) works on both msvs and gcc.

```
typedef std::map<double,double> Map;
typedef Map::iterator MapIter;

void rotate( Map &m ) {
    if ( m.empty() ) return;
    MapIter prev, iter = m.begin(), max_iter = m.end();
    Map::key_type rem_key = iter->first;
    Map::mapped_type rem_val = iter->second;
    for( prev = iter++; iter != max_iter; prev = iter++ )  {
        Map::key_type *key = const_cast<Map::key_type*>(&prev->first);
        *key = iter->first - rem_key;
        prev->second = iter->second;
    }
    prev->second = rem_val;
}
```

**EDIT**: described rotation operation does not change related keys positions only in case all keys are nonnegative. In other case my algorithm modifies the map structure incorrectly and thereby cannot be used.

Comment: The keys in a map are not modifiable. You can modify them only by using the const_cast which should not be done, as you also mention.

Comment: @Jiri. You are wright. I groundlessly assumed that all the keys are nonnegative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I read your comment but I still felt like providing an answer and show how it can be done by using the original map. So, here's the code:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main() {
    std::map <double, double> test;

    test[0.5] = 15;
    test[1] = 20;
    test[2.3] = 12;
    test[3.7] = 18;

    std::pair<double, double> first = *test.begin();
    test.erase(test.begin());
    std::map<double, double>::iterator i = test.begin();
    while ( i != test.end() ) {
        test[i->first - first.first] = i->second;
        std::map <double, double>::iterator prev = i;
        ++i;
        test.erase(prev);
    }
    test[test.rbegin()->first + first.first] = first.second;

    for ( i = test.begin(); i != test.end(); ++i ) {
        std::cout << "test[" << i->first << "] = " << i->second << "\n";
    }
}
```

A few notes:

- `std::map` keys cannot be modified, so you have to remove old elements and insert new ones;
- The problem statement guarantees that the newly inserted elements will not overwrite existing ones;
- Removing elements from a map doesn't invalidate iterators that do not point to removed elements.

Comment: Take a closer look at key value set. Keys are not simply rotated. Their values are modified too.

Comment: @tyz: You're absolutely, right. I provided a - hopefully - corrected version.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea.

Use two data structures instead of one.  Keep the values in a `list<double>`, and represent your map as `map<double, list<double>::iterator>`.

That is, map from `double` keys to iterators (i.e. pointers) into the value list.

Also keep track of how many rotations you have performed total; call it `k`.  To perform a lookup, look up the key in the map, add `k` to the iterator, and dereference it.  (Yes, this is O(k).)  Also, for this to work, you need a circular linked list; or more easily, implement your own march through the list that handles wrap-around.

Note that in general, you do not rotate the list itself; you just increment `k`.  All of the cost is incurred during lookup.

Note that insertions are still `O(log n)` since inserting in a list does not invalidate its iterators, and you can obtain the location to insert into the list in `O(log n)` time from the map.

Now here is the original bit.  When `k` reaches `sqrt(n)`, *then* you actually rotate the list to reset `k` to zero.  This operation is `O(n)`, but you only do it once every `O(sqrt(n))` rotations...  Meaning the *amortized* (i.e. average) cost of your rotate operation is also `O(sqrt(n))`.  And `k` is never greater than `sqrt(n)`, so lookups are also `O(sqrt(n))`.

Thus, this formulation provides:

Insert: O(log n)
Delete: O(log n)
Lookup: O(sqrt(n))
Rotate: O(sqrt(n))

Which you might or might not consider better than the other suggestions, but at least it's different...

Also with this formulation you can trade off lookup for rotation speed.  For example, if you do the "reset" operation when `k` reaches `log n`, your rotations will take `O(n / log n)` on average but lookups will still be `O(log n)`.  (Most of the other proposals here either have rotations taking `O(n)` or insertions taking `O(n)`, so this version beats those...  Although only by a factor of log n.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do rotation in O(log N)

```
#include<map>

using namespace std;

map<double, double> m;
double diff; //the keys in m are actually diff bigger then in needed map

void rotate()
{
     double savedValue = m.begin()->second;
     double removedKey = m.begin()->first - diff;//save the value of first element
     m.erase(m.begin()); //erase first element
     diff += removedKey; //do the (key -=) thing
     m[m.rbegin()->second + removedKey] = savedValue;//add new value
}

//dont need to do this, just remember that key = storedKey - diff
map<double, double> getMap()
{
        map<double, double> res;
        for(map<double, double>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
                m[it->first-diff] = it->second;
        return res;
}
```

Comment: +1 I think that's optimal solution if we want to be able to easily modify the map (like insert new elements) after the rotations. You should add the code that explicitly shows how to perform lookup and insert using the diff variable.

Comment: you've got a bug in your code, there should be `diff += removedKey - diff;` or simply `diff = removedKey;`

Comment: and the next line is broken as well, so I guess it's easiest to fix everything in the second line of rotate(): `double removedKey = m.begin()->first - diff;`

Comment: Thanks. I really should have written it all at paper first.

Answer (score 0):

I note that, as long as keys are neither added nor removed from the map by any other means, it is possible to keep track of the key changes during rotation.

First of all, note that the largest key in the map never changes.

Now notice that, except for key values that get "wrapped round" from one extreme of the map to another, you can summarise the effect of the rotations by keeping track of the total value of the keys that are subtracted.

Look what happens to the smallest key - you can imagine that it is subtracted by itself, to produce a value of zero. But now we decide that the value 0 is too small to put up with, and just like modular arithmetic, we can add a modulus to it to bring it back into range. That value is the (unchanging) largest key in the map. So the rule for predicting keys forwards, is to subtract the sum of all the smallest keys dealt with so far, and then add the largest key value as many times as is required to bring the value into range. Similarly, the rule for deducing keys backwards will be to subtract the sum of all the smallest keys dealt with so far, and then to add the largest key value as many times as is required to bring the value into range.

Using this, you should be able to allow users to rotate the map and to look up key values at O(1) cost, only having to handle the O(n log n) - (or possibly O(n) depending on how tricky and careful you want to be) job of rewriting the map when they add or remove key values.

I think that looking up values by order index (e.g. 1st value, 2nd value, 3rd value) is the same principle - keep track of a value to add or subtract that accounts for the total rotation so far, and add or subtract the total number of items in the map to bring things back into range.

Comment: [-1:0, 0:1] -> [-1:0, 1:1]. The largest key in the map changes.

Comment: In the case where the first key is -ve the old last key does indeed increase, and the renumbered first key is smaller than it - so we do not in fact have a rotation. If the first key is >= 0, then the old last key is no bigger, and the renumbered first key becomes equal to the value of the previous last key. I guess my method works only for the case when the lowest key is >= 0 and we really do have a rotation.

Answer (score 0):

If after rotations you only need to perform lookups effectively then you should go for Matthieu's solution.
In his excellent answer he only forgot that rather than `Key^i[n]` you need an inverse of that function ie given some value `k` and number of rotations `i` what will be the rank (index) `n` of key `k` after `i` rotations (if such a key exists).

I don't think the inverse function can be found in analytical terms and computed in O(1) the way `Key^i[n]` was, but you can do effective lookups in O(log n) time using a binary search.

```
double get(Vector const& vec, size_t const i, double key) {
    assert(n < vec.size() && "Wrong index");
    size_t rank = binarySearch(vec, i, 0, vec.size()-1, key);
    if (rank < 0) {
        // not found, return NaN or something
    }
    return vec[rank].second;    
}

size_t binarySearch(Vector const& vec, size_t const i, size_t const low, size_t const high, double value) {
    if (high < low)
        return -1; // not found
    mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
    if (key(vec, i, mid) > value)
        return binarySearch(vec, i, low, mid-1, value);
    else if (key(vec, i, mid) < value)
        return binarySearch(vec, i, mid+1, high, value);
    else
        return mid; // found
}
```

This solution gives you O(1) rotations (you only need to increment rotations counter and remember it) and O(log n) lookups.
If you want to modify the map (like insert a new element) you'd have to reset the whole map using the getMap() function, this takes O(n) time.

So if you need to do effectively lookups and insertions (removals, etc) after rotations then you should stick to kilotaras' solution, which gives you uniformly O(log n) time for all the operations including rotations, lookups and modifications.